# Share DLL between 2 process in .net

Tags: c#, .net, shared-libraries, shared-memory

I have 2 Winforms project and 1 Library project in my solution, this 2 winforms will be launched independently by the user.

What happens right now is that the shared DLL is instantiated in memory per process, even if both exes are in the same folder or if the DLL is in the GAC.

But I wish I could reuse the same DLL between those 2 process.

---

I found a workaround, create a third project and instantiate the winforms project from there, in this case the DLL will be only instantiated once in memory. But I don't like to have an extra project for this to work. Any other Solution?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why? Are you having memory usage issues? Are you trying to share `static` or `AppDomain` state between the applications?

Comment: AFAIK, there's no simple way of doing this. Both applications are running in their own AppDomain which isolates them from stepping on each other's toes. I believe when you launch it via your own launcher application, they end up being executed in the same AppDomain which lets them share static state (but it also means one application can adversely influence the other). Perhaps there's an easier way, but you can try looking up [C# inter-process communication](https://www.google.ca/webhp#q=C%23%20inter%20process%20communication)